# The SSH GitHub route flags unknown when turning off the machine or something

Tags: git, github, ssh

A day earlier I add the `ssh{origin rout}` and it's working with `git@{user}/{repo}.git` as it's supposed to do.

The day after I turn on the machine starting a few commits but when pushing it says things like unknown rout and check permissions until I run `` git bash `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` ``  remove the route `git remote remove` then add it again.

I need to go back and forth between VS Code and git bash to set it back on.

Answer (score 0):

Removing/Adding the remote origin should not be needed: it does not change anyway.
You would need to update something only when (as [explained here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_troubleshooting-hanging-or-failing-connections)) if your dynamically routes an SSH connection to one node from a cluster each time an SSH connection is made.

This is an issue for VS Code because it makes two connections to open a remote window: the first to install or start the VS Code Server (or find an already running instance) and the second to create the SSH port tunnel that VS Code uses to talk to the server.
If VS Code is routed to a different machine when it creates the second connection, it won't be able to talk to the VS Code server.

If that is not the case for you, all you need is to automate the [`ssh-agent` launch, once per session](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases).